# Why Hibernate didn't make session as Auto Closeable?

Tags: java, hibernate, session, try-catch

Why Hibernate didn't make sessions as auto Closeable?Is is something do with the design of session.

Should we write our own wrapper class to do this so be can use the ARM feature of Java 7?

Comment: Session factory generate session object for you each and every time.session can be auto flush you just need to configure it in a way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate is compatible with Java 6. Since `AutoCloseable` was introduced in Java 7, it can only be used by software requiring Java 7. A version of Hibernate requiring Java 7 would probably contain `Session` implementing `AutoCloseable`.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in hibernate version 5.
If you can upgrade to version 5, please use this.
Supported Jira ticket

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8898

For project which cannot upgrade, for that we can implement our own **CloseableSession** interface.

```
public class CloseableSession implements AutoCloseable {

    private final Session session;

    public CloseableSession(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        return session;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Usage

```
try (CloseableSession session = new CloseableSession(
                sessionFactory.openSession())) {

}
```